# Access docker volume via url

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-web-api, docker-volume

I created a small webapi with c# that lets my users upload images. The method looks like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateXXX(ADto dto)
{
    // Save the image in a docker volume
}
```

The `CreateXXX` method takes `ADto` as parameter that contains some properties, one beeing my image, base64 encoded. What I'm basically doing here is quite simple: I decode the image and then, since my webapi service is hosted in a docker container, I'm saving it in a docker volume. Everything is working fine, I can see that the image was saved on my host (the volume that I mapped).

Now, I created a get on my webapi service that returns the image back to the client. Again, it's `ADto` that contains some properties, one beeging **the path** of my image on the disks (my docker-volume). The path looks like this: `/pictures/123456789.jpg`

The question is: how should the browser access the resource to display the image? Using http://localhost:5001/pictures/123456789.jpg is not working. (localhost:5001 is where my webapi is hosted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client browsers will never have access to your local filesystem. The only way that URL would be valid, is if you have a handler on your webserver that maps incoming requests to your local filesystem. It makes absolutely no difference whether your application runs inside a docker container or a server.

If you are using IIS as webserver, you could create a virtual directory and map it to your pictures directory on filesystem. If you are using Kestrel as the application server, you need to implement a handler to translate incoming requests to your picture files.

You need to be more specific about what technologies you have used, otherwise it is not possible to help further.

Comment: Actually you put me in the right direction: I'm using Kestrel, and did `app.UseStaticFiles();` but it seems that I have to manually specify the folder with the overloaded method of `UseStaticFiles` (the one which takes a `StaticFileOption` as parameter). Now it's working!